# Can't open Windows Phone 8.1 project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Just yesterday i have installed Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 on my working station. Everything goes fine until i tried to open my Universal Windows Store project. Projects what using Windows Phone 8.1 SDK isn't loaded and requiring an update.

`One or more projects require a platform SDK (WindowsPhoneApp, Version=8.1).`

Link from Studio to download missing SDK is redirecting me to www.microsoft.com. I tried to install everything i could find referring to this SDK, but couldn't solve this problem. On other machines everything work just fine. What should i do with this problem?

Comment: running the same problem on my internship, download the SDK and it will work, however, Windows 10 has no emulators yet for Windows Phone so you won't be able to run your code.

Comment: @katherina i have emulators for both wp 8.1 and wp 10. And both running well.

Comment: o.O Rly? how is that even possible.

Comment: @katherina why it shouldn't be? If you dont have those, maybe you didn't installed environment in your studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do an install of Visual Studio 2015, you need to do a custom install. One of the selections should be Windows 8.1 Phone. If you do not check this box, the SDK will not be available. To install Open your control panel and go to Programs and features. Scroll down to Visual Studio 2015 and click change. A Visual Studio installer will pop up. Click Modify and install 8.1 Universal.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 installs only Windows 10 SDK, which allows you to develop Universal Apps. If you need Windows Phone 8.1, you need to download and install the [Windows Phone 8.1 Update & Emulator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=43719). This download will install the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK as well as 6 emulators to work with.

Comment: Have VS 2017 Enterprise (15.8.9), after installing this update, nothing changed, still cannot load old WP81 projects :(